# encrypted specfiec json data using python

Tags: python, tkinter, cryptography

I'm working on a Tkinter app in which the user adds their credential like user_name and password and I store it in a JSON file. when the user selects data from treeview the particular data send to the website now my concern is to encrypt the username and password of the user and when the user selects data only decrypted data send to the website. and users can also add new data and update data.

Is there any solution to this problem? your support will be appreciated.

```
key=Fernet.generate_key()
f=Fernet(key)
def generate_key(path='secret.key'):
    """ Generates a key and save it into a file.  """
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open(path, "wb") as file:
        file.write(key)
    return Fernet(key)
def load_key(path='secret.key'):
    """ Load a previously generated key. """
    with open(path, 'rb') as file:
        key = file.read()
    return Fernet(key)
def encrypt(message: str, f: Fernet):
    return f.encrypt(str(message).encode())
def decrypt(message: bytes, f: Fernet):
    return f.decrypt(message).decode()
def load_json(path):
    """ Loads a json file.  """
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    return data
def protect(data: Union[dict, str, bytes], fields: Union[dict, bool], f: Fernet, encode=True):
    if isinstance(fields, bool) and fields is True:
        return encrypt(data, f) if encode else decrypt(data, f)
    if isinstance(fields, dict):
        for key, value in fields.items():
            data[key] = protect(data[key], value, f, encode=encode)
    return data

#------------------LOAD SETTING AND KEYS--------------------------
settings = load_json(settingfile)
key, fields = settings['pathKey'], settings['fields']
if not os.path.exists(key):
    f = generate_key(key)
else:
    f = load_key(key)

       data = load_json(datafile)# changed
        process_request('_UPDATE_',uname,ulink,usname,passd)
        for idx ,enitity in enumerate(data):
            data[:][idx]=protect(enitity,fields,f)
            a=str(data)
            a=a.replace("b'",'"')
            a=a.replace("'",'"')
        with open(datafile, 'w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(a)
```

Above is the code that I used but it encrypts over encrypted previous data.

Comment: Your code does not call `encrypt()` or `decrypt()`, so it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 i have updated code kindly check.